# Why won't my Riolu evolve?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Recently I asked [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204300/what-is-the-love-requirement-to-evolve-riolu-and-how-can-i-quickly-increase-i) on how I can evolve my Riolu at Level 2 and most of the feedback said to raise its happiness to max and then level it up.

After a long, long while of IV Breeding, Ev Training through Super Training (because I didn't want Riolu to level up), plus tons of vitamins and long rides on my bicycle around the Battle Resort with Befriending Power Lvl 1 because I haven't unlocked 2 and 3, I go to Verdanturf Town to check the happiness of Riolu and she says that it can't love me any more than it already does.

So I think to myself that FINALLY got the perfect Riolu. Then, I feed it a Rare Candy and... Nothing. Then I think that Riolu needs to level up in battle so I go to Route 101 and fight a Level 2 Wurmple and Riolu levels up but still nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: You seem to have taken the right steps, but Riolu only evolves during the day. In Gen VI thats between 11 AM and 6 PM, confirm this is the time on your 3DS when you try to evolve it. Changing the time of the 3DS makes this evolution (and other time-based events) impossible for 24 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the others have mentioned you must follow these rules in order for it to work:

1. **Have high friendship** - I make mine hold a Soothe Bell and give it some berries that boost friendship, however these can also lower the stats.
2. **Level Up during the day** - This is between 10am and 6pm (Check your 3DS clock), however **DO NOT** change the time as that will stop all timed events for 24 hours.

If you follow those rules your Riolu shall evolve into Lucario. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have high enough friendship it should evolve when leveled up, but the part you are missing is that it needs to be day. Other than that, I don't know.